# C# How to read lines from a Stream object

Tags: c#, zip

I am trying to read the first two lines from a .txt file inside a Zip file.  I don't want or need to save the whole file to disk.  I can get to the zip archive entity easily enough:

```
ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(fileName);

ZipArchiveEntry en = archive.Entries.FirstOrDefault(e =>
        Path.GetExtension(e.Name) == ".txt");
```

Using

```
en.Open()
```

only returns a Stream, not StreamReader so I can't use

```
en.ReadLine()
```

So how can I read just read the first two lines?

Thank you.

Comment: "only returns a Stream, not StreamReader so I can't use" - what's stopping you from creating a `StreamReader` from the `Stream`? The whole *point* of `StreamReader` is to allow you to read text from a `Stream`.

Comment: I've never done that.  I've searched "Convert Stream to StreamReader" and the answers I saw didn't seem to do what I needed.  Can you please give some example code?

Comment: Well have you looked at how you can construct a StreamReader? Always look at the API documentation...

Comment: Side note: you are missing `using` on the zip and stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer some knowledge from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-io-streamreader-ctor(system-io-stream)).

But in short, just create instance of StreamReader with param is Stream you got from "en.Open()"

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(en.Open()))
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly.  I don't know why the answers I looked at were so complicated.